# Probability question involving MAP estimation

Tags: probability

You are given a coin that may or may not be biased. Specifically,
you have three hypotheses about the coin:

$H1$ = “the coin has probability $\frac12$ of landing heads”

$H2$ = “the coin has probability $\frac13$of landing heads”

$H3$ = “the coin has probability $\frac23$ of landing heads”

Suppose your priors for the hypotheses are

$P(H1)$ = 1/3

$ P(H2)$ = 1/3

$P(H3)$ = 1/3

You toss the coin seven times and observe five heads. Which is the maximum a
posteriori hypothesis?

I have been struggling with MAP Estimation and I can't quite understand how to break down the variables, where they fit in a formula.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the hypotheses are equiprobable a priori, the one that makes the data most likely is the most probable a posteriori. Since $\frac57\gt\frac23$, this is clearly $H_3$, but you can also explicitly calculate the probabilities using the binomial distribution.

Comment: how did you get $\frac 57$?

Comment: @user_456059239: The proportion of heads observed in the data. If it's greater than the expected proportion under all hypotheses, it seems safe to assume without explicit calculation that the hypothesis with the greatest expected proportion makes the data most likely.